# Have a dynamic form based on select choice in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

Does Rails or Simple_Form provide an easy way to show & hide different parts of a form depending on other options?

Here is a form where first a user selects a city.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <%= m.association :city, class: "form-control" %>
</div>
```

Then depending on the selected city, I would like to show only the neighborhoods relevant to this city. Currently I loop through ALL cities, and I'm considering adding a class to all checkboxes for a particular city and using JS to hide them when a city selection is made. This sounds hacky. Do you know a better alternative?

```
<% City.all.each do |city| %>
    <%= m.association :neighborhoods, as: :check_boxes, 
        collection: 
            Neighborhood.joins(:city)
                .where("cities.name = ?", city.name)
                .order(name: :asc) 
    %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is a super easy way to do this with Rails. But there is a more elegant way to handle the JS updates. You could use an AJAX call to update your checkbox div with a neighborhood partial depending on the city selected. It would look something like this (you'll have to fill in the gaps between your code and my code):

in the main HTML file:

```
<%=javascript_tag do%>
    $("#city-select").change(function(){
        var city_id = $(this).val();
        url = '/cities/'+city_id+'/get_neighbor_checkboxes';
        $.get(url, function(data){$('#checkbox_div').html(data)});
    });
<%end%>
```

in the controller:

```
def get_neighbor_checkboxes
    @neighborhoods = Neighborhood.find_by(:city_id => params[:id])
    # or whatever query you need to get your neighborhoods
    render :partial => 'checkboxes', :layout => nil
end
```

lastly, the "checkboxes.html.erb" partial view:

```
<%@neighborhoods.each do |n|%>
    # add your checkbox for each neighborhood n
<%end%>
```

Comment: I'd have to somehow pass the form builder though to the checkboxes.html.erb. Is that possible?

Comment: I don't think you can pass the form builder through. The best way would probably be to use check_box_tag and just check what 'name' and 'id' are assigned to an example checkbox in the form builder. Then assign those options manually in the check_box_tag. Or it might just be easier to add the checkbox with HTML instead of of the helper. Either way it should be quick.

Comment: I think you'd need a route to the url too